# Retrieving value of elements inside a parser object in iOS

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am working on a project which calls an API which returns an Xml data and inside my code classes are there to parse that data and extracting it to display on UI(NSXMLParser is used here).I am attaching the screen shot of xml response and the portion of code written to extract that parsed data(Parsing code I am not pasting here)

[image]

Code for extraction:

```
 else if ([adType isEqualToString:@"textAd"])
    {
        NSString *html = [xml.documentRoot     getNamedChild:@"htmlString"].text;

        CGSize bannerSize;
        if(adspaceHeight > 0 && adspaceWidth > 0)
        {
            bannerSize = CGSizeMake(adspaceWidth, adspaceHeight);
        }
        else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            bannerSize = CGSizeMake(728, 90);
        }
        else
        {
            bannerSize = CGSizeMake(320, 50);
        }

        UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bannerSize.width, bannerSize.height)];

        //load HTML string later (to avoid calling impression pixels when using custom events)
        if(!headers) { //means that it's an interstitial ad
            _htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<style>*
          { -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);} body {height:100%%;                width:100%%;
} 
       img {max-width:100%%;
       max-height:100%%; width:auto; height:auto; position: absolute; margin: auto; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;}
</style>
%@",html];
        } else {
            _htmlString = html;
        }


        if([skipOverlay isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

            wasUserAction = NO;

            webView.delegate = (id)self;
            webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];

            [webView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

            tap.delegate = self;


        } else {

            webView.delegate = nil;
            webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

//          add overlay later, only if no custom event is shown
        }
        webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        webView.opaque = NO;
        webView.scrollView.scrollsToTop = false;

        self.bannerView = webView;
  }
```

Now for me I want to modify the same code for another xml structure...
I am pasting the screenshot of response that I have to work on.Please help me to retrieve the data inside each node.(Especially there are two links inside the "ads" tag.How to retrieve them separately).
[image]

Comment: it will be good if you can provide the code and xml response as text in question.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr: Ok I will edit it.